# Photoshop CS4 - Save For Web using a Group of layers

Tags: photoshop-cs4

In photoshop CS4, is there a way to save a group of layers for Web?  I'm working off of a PSD and I have a small group of images that I want to save as one transparent png, while preserving their spatial relationship to each other.

I imagine there's a way to save the group for the web.  Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save for web only accept JPEG, PNG or GIF. These file types don't support layers a like pdf for example.

all layers of your group are flatten in the save for web mode